# finalize() activity onClicListener dont return previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two Activities `MainActivity` and `OtherActivity` from Main i call Other and wait for result

```
final Intent other = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(other, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

in the `OtherActivity` i have a Button for finish the process

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_finish);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "Closing");
        setResult(COMPLETE_PROCESS);
        finalize();
    }
});
```

the problem is the `OtherActivity` remains on the screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `finish()` not `finalize()`

Answer (score 2):

Change `finalize();` to `finish()`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "Closing");
    setResult(COMPLETE_PROCESS);
    finish();
```

`Activity` doesn't have a `finalize()` method but it does have a `finish()` method which closes the `Activity`